# How to create a tcp redirection to another computer in LAN Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, redirect

I want to redirect all tcp requests coming on a pc to another computer. How can I do that?

Forexample: I want that all the tcp requests coming to 10.42.43.10:5000 are redirected to 10.42.43.25:6000. Can I do that with a linux command?

Comment: I'd advise to read the iptables documentation, but not on an empty stomach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use redir command

redir [--laddr=incoming.ip.address] [--bind_addr=my.other.ip.address]